# dynamically generate html checkbox using php

Tags: php, mysql, checkbox

dI have a very small script that I am using to create dynamic content from a MySQL table. When I insert php into my code, it seems to overwrite the values.

My script is the following:

```
   <?php
    include 'auto_loader.php';
    include 'db.php';
    $database = new Database();
    $database->query('Select * FROM barber_dev.services');
    $rows = $database->resultset();
    foreach ($rows as $key => $value) {

      echo '
      <div class="label-container">
          <input type="checkbox" name="services[]" id="'+$value['services']+'" value="HairCut">
          <label for="Haircut">Haircut</label>
      </div>
              ';
 }

     ?>
```

I would except to see about 10 checkboxes with the php rendering valid id values. What I get instead is 0 checkboxes and the actual values. I am probably missing something extremely basic, but any help would greatly be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using wrong concatenation operator.

You should use `.` in PHP for concat not `+`.

Try below code

```
echo '
  <div class="label-container">
      <input type="checkbox" name="services[]" id="services" value="' . $rows['services'] . '">
      <label for="' . $rows['services'] . '">' . $rows['services'] . '</label>
  </div>
';
```

Comment: Thanks. Sometimes it's hard jumping from JavaScript back to PHP I get my concatenations all mixed up. I really appreciate the fast response. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `.` for concatenation in php, not `+` so try something like

```
 echo '
  <div class="label-container">
      <input type="checkbox" name="services[]" id="'.$value['services'].'" value="HairCut">
      <label for="Haircut">Haircut</label>
  </div>
          ';
```

hope that helps